# Conditional Expectation and Covariance

Tags: linear-algebra, conditional-expectation

Prove or disprove:

$\frac{\mathbb{E}[Y|X]- \mathbb{E}[Y] }{X-\mathbb{E}[X]} = \frac{Cov(X,Y)}{Cov(X,X)}$ ?

I have tried the following:

Since $Cov(X,Y) = Cov(X, \mathbb{E}[Y|X])$ and $ \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]] = \mathbb{E}[Y]$
We start with:

$Cov(X, Y) = Cov(X, \mathbb{E}[Y|X]) = \mathbb{E}[X \times\mathbb{E}[Y|X]] - \mathbb{E}[X]\times \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]] = \mathbb{E}[X\ \mathbb{E}[Y|X]] - \mathbb{E}[X]\ \mathbb{E}[Y]$

Not sure what $\mathbb{E}[X\ \mathbb{E}[Y|X]]$ further reduces to.

Comment: 1) Please use [LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) for typesetting math. 2) "What have you tried?"

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! As this site is meant to be a useful repository rather than a Do My Homework forum, it's common courtesy to show what you've already tried, and really narrow down what you're struggling with. Most people here are glad to help once you've adequately motivated the problem. [Quick Guide](http://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067/21813) to attracting answers and preventing your question from being deleted. Good luck!

Comment: There must be a mistake in the statement: the RHS is a number, while in the LHS, the numerator is a number and the denominator is a random variable.

Comment: @Carnby $E[X|Y]$ is also a random variable.

Comment: The purpose is to finally arrive at vector version

$\mathbb{E}[Y|X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] + \sum_{XY}^{'}\sum_{XX}^{-1} (X-\mathbb{E}(X))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I am posting an answer because OP has now shown some effort. It received some close votes earlier when no attempt was shown].

The statement is of the following form: $E[Y|X]=a+bX$ for some constants  $a$ and $b$. This is clearly false for $Y=X^{2}$ (and  a suitable $X$, for example any continuous r.v.).

Comment: Are you saying this whole thing looks like an assumption rather than a statement that I vainly try to prove?

Comment: I have shown that it cannot be proved. @Toby1729